Index a batch of numpy vectors with a batch of numpy index matrices
If I have a vector vec, I can index it with a matrix as follows:
import numpy as np

vec = np.asarray([1,2,3,4]) # Shape (4,)

mat = np.asarray([[0,2],
                  [3,1]]) # Shape (2,2)

result = vec[mat] # Shape (2,2)


# result = array([[1, 3],
#              [4, 2]])


Now suppose I have batches of vectors and matrices instead.
What would be the simplest way to do the same kind of indexing for each element in the batch, strictly using numpy? For instance:
vecs = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   [5, 6, 7, 8],
                   [9,10,11,12]]) # Shape (3,4)

mats = np.asarray([ [[0,1],
                     [1,0]],
                    [[0,2],
                     [1,1]],
                    [[3,1],
                     [0,0]] ]) # Shape (3,2,2)

# results = np.asarray([ [[1,2],
#                         [2,1]],
#                        [[5,7],
#                         [6,6]],
#                        [[12,10],
#                         [9,9]] ]) # Shape (3,2,2)

What about higher-dimensional batches? Is there a simple and general way to vectorize such indexing to arbitrary batches?

vecs[np.arange(len(mats))[:,None,None], mats]

Add a (3,1,1) array to index the first dimension:
In [196]: vecs[np.arange(3)[:,None,None],mats]
Out[196]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  1]],

       [[ 5,  7],
        [ 6,  6]],

       [[12, 10],
        [ 9,  9]]])

This will broadcast with your (3,2,2) mats.

I see. Any way to do this for an arbitrary batch shape? Maybe something with ogrid...

ix_ is commonly used to make broadcastable indices, but requires 1d inputs. take_along_axis requires a 2d mats.  I don't know how arbitrary you have in mind.  The underlying principle still applies - broadcasting.

Yes, ix_ works, thanks.
